# JSTL c:out not showing the variable's value

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, taglib

I'm following a tutorial [about spring](http://www.uv.es/grimo/teaching/SpringMVCv3PasoAPaso/part2.html) and I'm supposed to set a variable in a controller in order to be printed within the jsp rendering the request. The code is as follows:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello.htm")
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String now = (new Date()).toString();
        return new ModelAndView("WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp", "now", now);
    }
}
```

Then, the hello.jsp code is as follows:

```
<%@ page session="true"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Greetings, it is now <c:out value="${now}" /></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am expected to get an html showing this:

```
Greetings, it is now Mon Fri Dec 06 00:39:35 CET 2013
```

But all I get is:

```
Greetings, it is now ${now}
```

I've checked everything twice (or even more!) but everything seems to be as the tutorial says but there must be something missing, I hope...

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: I think you coded hello controller wrong.  You need to put now into a MAP with key is now.

Comment: I've also tried the following code without any success:

    `Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("now", now);
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("hello.jsp");
    mav.addAllObjects(params);
    return mav;`

Comment: Please post your full web.xml.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is an **E** xpression **L** anguage issue. Your `${}` is not being resolved. This can happen for a number of reasons. One, and the most likely, is that your web.xml is declaring Servlet 2.3 and under. You'll have to specify 2.4+. Now, obviously, your Servlet container must also support that higher version.

Comment: It worked! I've changed to 2.5, as in the tutorial, and now it parses the expressions. Thank you Sotirios, you hit the nail on the head!! I created the webapp by using the maven's archetype and you get 2.3 version servlet by default.

Comment: maven 3 still generates web.xml with servlet 2.3

Answer (score 3):

Change this - the pad a library is bad:

```
<!--  %@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>-->
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```